# Search matching data on list/datatable and table

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to search all requests that matches certain regular expression (simple wildcards mostly), but I am not sure how to proceed. I can easily do this with a single endpoint, where I would use it directly in the query, but I have multiple endpoints per type/group of requests I want to get data for (for example, I need all request for login that matches multiple endpoints, same for, logouts, posts, etc...).

I have, for example, a dynamic array (even tried with a string delimited by a semicolon, which I split) but I get the same error at the end.

```
let login = dynamic(["https://example.com/*/login*", "https://example.com/login*"]);
requests
| extend group = "Login"
| mv-expand endpoint = login
| where url matches regex endpoint
```

> 'matches regex' operator requires string arguments

Tried force casting and using typeof string, but that doesn't seem to help...

```
let login = dynamic(["https://example.com/*/login*", "https://example.com/login*"]);
requests
| extend group = "Login"
| mv-expand endpoint = login to typeof(string)
| where url matches regex tostring(endpoint) // tried with and without tostring
```

> matches regex: failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant

I tried using a datatable, I wanted to do something like this, but not sure how to proceed with that...:

```
let TEndpoints = datatable(group: string, endpoints: dynamic)
[
    "Login", dynamic(["https://example.com/*/login*", "https://example.com/login*"]),
    "Logouts", dynamic(["https://example.com/*/logout*", "https://example.com/logout*"]),
    "Register", dynamic(["https://example.com/*/register*", "https://example.com/register*"])
];
```

*Note that the endpoints are really just example. The wildcards are due to different locales and geo-regions.*

Anyone has any idea if this is achievable?

Thanks,

Comment: Would has_any() work for this case? (i.e. can you replace the regex with term matching)?

Answer (score 0):

That was a challenging one.

It seems all of KQL regex functions & operators accept only string literals / arguments as patterns, except for one exception I was able to identify in context of `print`, e.g.:

```
print str = 'A', pat = '.' 
| where str matches regex pat
```

or

```
print str = 'A', pat = '.' 
| union (print str = 'B', pat = '.')
| where str matches regex pat
```

I was also able to manipulate `partition by` and use is it to answer your question.

Please note that I am not projecting the `login` column within the `partition by` brackets, however I do use `login` later on with `match regex`.
My guess is that `login`, the partition value, is stored behind the scenes in a variable and therefore can be used with `match regex`.

P.S.
The patterns you supplied are not regex patterns, but globbing, so I changed them accordingly.

```
let requests = datatable(id:int, url:dynamic)
[
    1 ,dynamic(["https://example.com/login123","https://example.com/foo/bar/login123"]),
    2 ,dynamic(["https://example.com/tic/login","https://example.com/tic/login/tac/toe"])
];
let login = dynamic(["https://example.com/[^/]+/login.*", "https://example.com/login.*"]);
requests
| mv-expand url
| mv-expand login = login
| extend url = tostring(url), login = tostring(login)
| partition by login (project id, url | where url matches regex login)
```

| id | url |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | https://example.com/login123 |
| 2 | https://example.com/tic/login |
| 2 | https://example.com/tic/login/tac/toe |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4VRwU7DMAy9V8o/WD01EBZt3Ir4kqpIaWraoDQpiQedtI8nbbciJAbJIc57z8%20ybZEg4PsRI0V4hlZRuo3FwrSlcSTgGGzZnpwajOYsq1gG6exBXLCiynuiMZZS4qSG0eJO%200Fa3xm3Pzzm4lf61XvZqPAtq7lYnQ//OZPRa9oN642XpLQkj8mbZfUTy2xqdWHmPv%20sUb3I%20n512d3lAm63mOiaJ%20/rCFl2huHjAadRuXae3U/gWn55ZwonwlWYUPKRgnFdkb5cbOINXgA%20p40qkCHjHTSni64Yg39DTWDaZWlwhs8eAy7xoEj3GNOmO5zWBP4FAZiJv/oBAAA=)

Comment: Kind reminder to check the answer